# Problems with Azure SDK 2.5 (RoleEntryPoint) WorkerRole

Tags: c#, azure

I recently upgraded my project from Azure sdk 2.3 to sdk 2.5 and i've encountered a very frustrating problem.
I'm using the following code:

**ThreadedRoleEntryPoint1.cs**

```
public abstract class ThreadedRoleEntryPoint1 : RoleEntryPoint
{
    protected ThreadedRoleEntryPoint1()
    {
        Threads = new List<Thread>();
        EventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
    }

    private List<Thread> Threads;
    private WorkerEntryPoint1[] _workers;
    protected EventWaitHandle EventWaitHandle;

    public WorkerEntryPoint1[] workers { get; set; }

    public override void Run()
    {
        foreach (WorkerEntryPoint1 worker in _workers) { Threads.Add(new Thread(worker.ProtectedRun)); }

        foreach (Thread thread in Threads) { thread.Start(); }

        while (!EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(0))
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < Threads.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!Threads[i].IsAlive)
                {
                    Threads[i] = new Thread(_workers[i].Run);
                    Threads[i].Start();
                }
            }

            EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
        }
    }

    //public override bool OnStart(WorkerEntryPoint1[] workers)
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        this._workers = workers;

        foreach (WorkerEntryPoint1 worker in workers) { worker.OnStart(); }

        return base.OnStart();
    }

    //public override bool OnStart()
    //{
    //    throw (new InvalidOperationException());
    //}

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        EventWaitHandle.Set();

        foreach (Thread thread in Threads) { while (thread.IsAlive) { thread.Abort(); } }

        foreach (Thread thread in Threads) { while (thread.IsAlive) { Thread.Sleep(10); } }

        foreach (WorkerEntryPoint1 worker in _workers) { worker.OnStop(); }

        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

**WorkerEntryPoint1.cs**

```
public abstract class WorkerEntryPoint1
{
    public virtual bool OnStart()
    {
        return (true);
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnStop()
    {

    }

    internal void ProtectedRun()
    {
        try
        {
            Run();
        }

        catch (SystemException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**WorkerRole.cs**

```
internal class GlobalWorkerRole : ThreadedRoleEntryPoint1
{
    public GlobalWorkerRole()
    {
        _maxConnections = 10
    }

    private readonly int _maxConnections;

    public override void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            base.Run();
        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(error.ToString(), "EXCEPTION");
            throw error;
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = _maxConnections;

        List<WorkerEntryPoint1> workers = new List<WorkerEntryPoint1>
        {
            new ParseFeedMultiThreadWorker(),
            new CheckFeedStateWorker(),
            new ParseNewProductsWorker(),
            new UpdateProductInformationWorker(),
            new CleanTablesWorker(),
            new RebuildTablesWorker()
        };

        this.workers = workers.ToArray();

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Since sdk 2.5 I get the following error in the Azure Emulator:

*[runtime] Role entrypoint could not be created: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class*

My guess is that this has something to do with the fact that ThreadedRoleEntryPoint1 inherits from RoleEntryPoint which calls the OnStart of the abstract class instead of the GlobalWorkerRole.

Anyone who understands and can help me fix this issue, thanks!

Trust is a weakness...

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with how the host searches for the entry point. It seems to find the first class that inherits from RoleEntryPoint and then instantiates that class instead of looking for a non-abstract class.

A workaround is to move the abstract class into a different assembly, and leave the class you want used in the worker role project.